# how join one field with unknown field in splunk and add description

Tags: join, ip, splunk

i want to join a subsearch with another search, but the problem is: the subsearch return a field (an IP) with a description field and i want to match that with any event with src_ip or dst_ip of inner search,

something like this:
source="source1"|join (src_ip or dst_ip) [search source="source2"|table IP,description]

i don't know which of src_ip or dst_ip match with "returned IP" !!

Answer (score 0):

It might be with a little overhead but you can do two consecutive inner joins one for the source ip and after that another one for destination.